# Quasar app typescript errors on brand new app

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I've created a brand new Quasar project using "npm init quasar". I'm getting all kinds of errors like the one shown below. I've not made any changes in the code. The project does seem to run properly.

Property 'QLayout' does not exist on type '{ "q-layout": GlobalComponentConstructor<QLayoutProps, QLayoutSlots>; } & { "q-header": GlobalComponentConstructor<QHeaderProps, QHeaderSlots>; } & ... 9 more ... & { ...; }'. Did you mean 'q-layout'?ts(2551)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm running typescript version 5.0.4. I found it by running tsc -v.

I needed to create a new tsconfig.json file by running tsc --init.

Last I added: "extends": "@quasar/app-vite/tsconfig-preset", and "baseUrl": ".", from the original tsconfig.json.